# Java indexOf returns unrealistic value

Tags: java, android, indexof

I have the following code:

```
String string = "string with delimiter appearing several times. this string contains delimiter appearing again and again and would be used to do something that a delimiter is used for.",
delimiter = "delimiter";

int beginIndex = 0, endIndex = 0;

beginIndex = string.indexOf(delimiter, beginIndex); // returns 13 as expected
endIndex = string.indexOf(delimiter, beginIndex + 1); // returns a 734 instead of the expected 68
```

This is the problem. I have no idea why `endIndex` is not assigned the value of the next occurrence of `delimiter` and instead gets assigned a value far much larger than the string length. Any ideas on how this could be solved?

**EDIT**
The above is an example scenario. The actual case here is that the value of `string` is the contents of http://sixcritics.com?json=1 whereas the actual returns are `beginIndex: 70, endIndex: 12046` for the value of delimiter being `"type":"post"`. The length of the string is less than 10000, and I have no idea where the 12046 is coming from.

Comment: Let me edti the question for the exact situation.

Comment: Just in case .. have a look at the example given in: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/251479 - does that relate to you?

Comment: @zapl actually, that is what I'm trying to achieve. I use `string.substring(beginIndex, endIndex)` to get the string between the two indices. This worked in other scenarios and happens not to work in this particular case for the reason stated in the question.

Comment: The string is 94557 of length, not less than 10000.
Also 12046 seem correct.

Comment: Also, I hope you're not using blind string scanning for actual JSON interpretation when there are several competent parsers available.

Comment: @chrylis I had to resolve to string scanning because using JSONObject and JSONArray in the fragment always resulted in the fragment getting reloaded each time it is started. I had another fragment that uses string scanning and it always retained its content.

Comment: You don't have to use string scanning, you could also fix the problem you have with using proper JsonObjects. That's likely the better approach. Most manual scanning attempts fail already at handling escape sequences like `"name": "James \"The Boss\" Dean"`, or when encountering slighly malformed json that a proper parser handles correctly. object mapping is maybe not ideal in your case, but there are all kinds of json parsers. (http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonStreamingApi for example)

Comment: @zapl maybe you should provide an answer for the question stackoverflow.com/questions/37642963/difference-between-string-scanning-and-json-parsing-for-a-json-string.